# Why exception System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, xamarin, task-parallel-library

I am building a xamarin android application but cant use async await.

The execution gets stuck for very long time and then finally throws exception with message: **System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled**

First I thought it's getting stuck because I din't use ConfigureAwait(false), but using it din't solve anything.

code:

```
protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    await ProcessData().ConfigureAwait(false); 
}

private async Task ProcessData()
{
    await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)).ConfigureAwait(false); // 2 seconds
}
```

stack trace:

```
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #6
11-11 15:11:06.144 W/        (19542): _wapi_connect: error looking up socket handle 0x26
11-11 15:11:06.177 D/Mono    (19542): DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
11-11 15:11:06.177 D/Mono    (19542): DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
11-11 15:11:06.177 D/Mono    (19542): DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
11-11 15:11:06.177 D/Mono    (19542): Searching for '__android_log_print'.
11-11 15:11:06.177 D/Mono    (19542): Probing '__android_log_print'.
11-11 15:11:06.177 D/Mono    (19542): Found as '__android_log_print'.
11-11 15:11:06.178 I/MonoDroid(19542): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
11-11 15:11:06.179 I/MonoDroid(19542): System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
11-11 15:11:06.179 I/MonoDroid(19542): at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x0004b>
11-11 15:11:06.179 I/MonoDroid(19542): at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (object) <IL 0x00006, 0x0003b>
11-11 15:11:06.179 I/MonoDroid(19542): at Android.App.SyncContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () <IL 0x0000c, 0x00032>
11-11 15:11:06.179 I/MonoDroid(19542): at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () <IL 0x00011, 0x0004c>
11-11 15:11:06.179 I/MonoDroid(19542): at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0000a, 0x0005e>
11-11 15:11:06.179 I/MonoDroid(19542): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.b257f262-40d0-43f7-b8b4-43d0ec65bc72 (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0001f>
11-11 15:11:06.186 W/art     (19542): JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable
11-11 15:11:06.188 D/AndroidRuntime(19542): Shutting down VM
An unhandled exception occured.

11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): Process: AndroidConsumer.AndroidConsumer, PID: 19542
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     ... 1 more
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x0004b>
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>m__0 (object) <IL 0x00006, 0x0003b>
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): at Android.App.SyncContext/<Post>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () <IL 0x0000c, 0x00032>
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () <IL 0x00011, 0x0004c>
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0000a, 0x0005e>
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.b257f262-40d0-43f7-b8b4-43d0ec65bc72 (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0001f>
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542): 
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
11-11 15:12:58.748 E/AndroidRuntime(19542):     ... 4 more
11-11 15:12:58.877 I/Process (19542): Sending signal. PID: 19542 SIG: 9
```

Comment: As you say that it is stuck for a long time, may be the problem in some other code? Or does the code you've posted reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add this to your code and then say what the message comes up with as a comment.

```
try 
{
    await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

In the catch loop, you can use any method you want to handle the error message, as long as you're able to view it.
Also, it's worth while putting all of that into a try and catch loop so you can check which part is coming up with the error.

Comment: Okay . I will put a try catch block now and see what happens